# Extract Mean Raster Value from multiple raster files into Excel

Tags: raster, excel, ndvi

I have a series of non-orthorectified raster files containing NDVI information.  I would like to extract the mean value from each raster so I can see a summary of each raster image name and the corresponding mean NDVI pixel value for each one.  I can achieve this for each raster individually using the raster layer statistics to html function but can't figure out how to achieve this so I can see the results for all of the raster files in one table.

I am not experienced with coding.